# R - Google Analytics Package

Tags: r, google-analytics-api

Is there an R package that connects to the Google Analytics API? Does anyone have any pointers otherwise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there's one option (that i am aware of) for explicitly connecting the two (Google Analytics & R).

This option requires R-DCOM (an interface to COM and DCOM to access R); you can get that [here](http://cran.r-project.org/contrib/extra/dcom/).

So i guess this is limited to Windows/.NET and C# (or any .NET language, i suppose).

I haven't used it (incompatible OS) but i have set it up for someone else; at least install & set-up are fairly straightforward:

- install DCOM
- then config--begin by executing the
  "dcomcnfg" in the console window
- this launches a component mgr; search
  StatConnectorSrv in DCOM components
  for 'properties'
- update the permissions--done.

There's a also complete **tutorial**, source code included (C#), for DCOM setup/install and building a small App that has programmatic access to Google Analytics and R, available [here](http://www.juanantonio.info/p_articles/archive/2007/BeyondGoogleAnalytics.htm).

But if all you want to do is get the data into R, all the pieces you need are readily available, e.g., my workflow:

1. export the data i need from the GA
   main panel. GA delivers your data in
   XML.
2. parse the raw data using the **XML** library (not part of the base distro, but available on [CRAN](http://mirrors.softliste.de/cran/))
3. (also pretty obvious) i store my
   data in an R dataframe (for analysis
   only, later it's broken up into
   tables and stored in a PostgreSQL
   database, using the **RPostgreSQL**
   package, which provides the drivers
   and R interface (DBI) to the pg
   database).

Lastly, it's not GA but another Google data resource with an R interface: the Omega Project has a fairly new R Package that provides an interface to GoogleTrends (called '**RGoogleTrends**'), available [here](http://www.omegahat.org/).

Comment: Doug, I think we spell it 'RPostgreSQL' not 'R-PostGreSQL' :)

Comment: Yes, thanks Dirk, editing now. Perhaps because i am not a native English speaker, words which have capital letters in the middle are a constant source of confusion for me. In the future, if you find it quicker/easier, just edit my post.

Comment: so this is a correct answer but unfortunately i'm an os x user however i'll reward the thorough nature. I could export the data manual but I'd like to automate the workflow. It looks like I'll be building an R wrapper for the Google Analytics API.

Answer (score 17):

http://code.google.com/p/r-google-analytics/

This package is now available

Comment: Great work, now submit it to CRAN.

Comment: (Since there's not really any other way to say this, it looks like you have two different accounts setup - you may want to put in a request to have your accounts merged.)

Comment: There is now a copy of CRAN

Answer (score 6):

I've put an updated version of the original r-google-analytics package on github: https://github.com/JerryWho/rgoogleanalytics
Here I've changed to version 2.4 of the API. The older version just used v2.3 which doesn't work since summer any more.

Comment: I had to rename this repository to https://github.com/JerryWho/rgoogleanalytics.old because I forked another repository and did some enhancements to it. The new one works with the current api. You can find it here: https://github.com/JerryWho/RGoogleAnalytics

Answer (score 5):

I'm actually building one now, i'll aim to get it onto CRAN as soon as possible

Comment: Wonderful!  Once you'll get it ready, I'f be very glad to know about it (and maybe write about it on r-statistics.com):  tal.galili@gmail.com

Comment: Very excited to see this as it develops!

Comment: Thanks Tal, that will be fantastic!

Answer (score 4):

A new package has just been announced:

http://github.com/sorenmacbeth/googleanalytics4r

Answer (score 3):

The Google Analytics API site has an example on how to retrieve analytics data using curl http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/2.0/gdataProtocol.html so supposedly you should be able to modify the examples and use Rcurl to retrieve the data.

There is a nice python package for getting data from GA that might give you some hints: http://github.com/clintecker/python-googleanalytics

Answer (score 3):

There is a recently released R library on CRAN that enables Google Analytics Data extraction into R. It supports Google Analytics Core Reporting API v3 and uses OAuth2.0 under the hood for Authorization. You may be able to install the library via

```
install.packages("RGoogleAnalytics")
```

Or in case if you want the development version from Github you can try

```
require(devtools)
devtools::install_github("Tatvic/RGoogleAnalytics")
```

Comment: I've edited my response by excluding the link and providing specific information on the R library requested by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

It would be fairly simple to create a wrapper using the RCurl and XML packages (very similar to the [nytR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nytR/index.html) or [RGoogleDocs](http://www.omegahat.org/RGoogleDocs/) packages).

Comment: " fairly simple " depends on who is creating the wrapper...

Answer (score 2):

Just to give an update, i've now created the base script, which currently does the following:

Create a new export object.
 Authenticate with your Google Account.
 Return an account profile for an authorised Google Account.
 Create a new API query
 Use the query to return a data.frame populated with metrics.

I've also built in some low level error handling of the parameter types, but on some of the more complex parameters like segment, i've left the errors to the GA API.

I just need to build out the unit tests and package this up, and we should be good to go.

Mike

Comment: link to it when you can please.

Answer (score 2):

I've found another R-package for Google Anayltics: http://skardhamar.github.com/rga/
It uses OAuth2 for authentication. 
I haven't tried it yet. But maybe that's the newest package out there.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be another Google Analytics-R package:
https://github.com/jdeboer/ganalytics/blob/master/README.md
I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: The ganalytics package is now available on CRAN and has interoperability with the googleAnalyticsR package which is also on CRAN. The former package makes it easy to dynamically define Google Analytics segments and filters. The latter offers the latest Google Analytics API features, including cohort analysis.